# The page isn't redirecting properly -localhost,php,mysqli

Tags: php, redirect, localhost

The first time I try the code it works very well, allow me to login and signout, but now all I keep getting is the page isn't redirecting properly error message

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';
include "navbar.php";
if(isset($_SESSION['userSession']) &&     !strstr($_SESSION['PHP_SELF'], "home.php"))
{
header("Location: about.php");
exit;
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
$email = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['user_email']));
$upass = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password']));

$query = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT user_id, user_email,     user_pass FROM users WHERE user_email='$email'");
$row=$query->fetch_array();

if(password_verify($upass, $row['user_pass']))
{
    $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['user_id'];
    header("Location: home.php");
}
else
{
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; email or password does not exists !
            </div>";
}

$MySQLi_CON->close();

}
?>
```

The above is my index page which offer login and  sign-up services before redirecting to home page

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['userSession']))  && !strstr($_SESSION['PHP_SELF'], "index.php"))
{
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
}

$query = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE
user_id=".$_SESSION['userSession']);
$userRow=$query->fetch_array();
$MySQLi_CON->close();
?>
```

The above is the home page, which the index page is supposed to redirect to
But I keep on getting the error message

Comment: use exit after `header("Location: home.php");`

Comment: Does `include "navbar.php";` output by any chance?

Comment: I have put the exist after header("location :home.php but it is not working

Comment: Include "navbar.php" is supposed to out my navbar.. But all the pages keep on producing the same error message

Comment: @Jon Stirling  thanks for the hint I just remove the session code in my navbar.php and everything starts working